# Nim. How to inherit all operations on distinct type?

Tags: nim-lang

Suppose, I have `type Radians = distinct float` and `type Degrees = distinct float`
This is not allowing me to use all operations available for floats, even most basic arithmetics `+`, `-`, `*`
Is there any way to sort of 'inherit' them all and use `distinct` only for compile-time checks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [Modeling Currencies](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#distinct-type-modeling-currencies) section from the Distinct type on the nim manual for the full example.

In summary:

Use the borrow pragma

```
proc `*` (x: int, y: Dollar): Dollar {.borrow.}
proc `div` (x: Dollar, y: int): Dollar {.borrow.}
```

Use templates to reduce boilerplate

```
template multiplicative(typ, base: typedesc) =
  proc `*` *(x: typ, y: base): typ {.borrow.}
  proc `*` *(x: base, y: typ): typ {.borrow.}
  proc `div` *(x: typ, y: base): typ {.borrow.}
  proc `mod` *(x: typ, y: base): typ {.borrow.}
```